# $H,K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic with $H \times K$ ; then is $H$ normal in $G$ ?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

Let $H,K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic with $H \times K$ ; then is $H$ normal in $G$ ? I can prove that $H \times \{e\}$ is normal in $H \times K$ but nothing else ; one thing is obvious is that if $H$ is normal in $G$ , then so is $K$ . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you making the assumption that $H\cap K = \{e\}$ and $HK = G$? Or are $H$ and $K$ arbitrary subgroups of $G$ with the property that $G \cong H\times K$?

Comment: @DanielFischer : No , no ; none of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a group $K_0$ and a subgroup $H_0$ of $K_0$ which is not normal. Then let

$$G = H_0 \times K_0,\quad K = \{e\} \times K_0,\quad H = \{e\} \times H_0.$$

By construction, $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times K$ since $H \cong H_0$ and $K \cong K_0$, and $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $K$, hence a fortiori not a normal subgroup of $K$.

The mere existence of *some* isomorphism $G \cong H\times K$ is a very weak condition. To be able to conclude that $H$ (or $K$) is a normal subgroup of $G$, we need further conditions on how $H$ and $K$ are embedded in $G$. It is not sufficient that $H\cap K$ be trivial, for example. To see that, consider a group that contains an isomorphic copy of itself as a non-normal subgroup. An example of such is the group

$$S = \bigl\{ \pi \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} : \pi \text{ is bijective and } \{ n : \pi(n) \neq n\} \text{ is finite}\bigr\},$$

in which the subgroups $S_k := \{ \pi \in S : \pi(k) = k\}$ are all isomorphic to $S$ but not normal. Then we can take $G = S\times S$, and for example $H = S_1\times \{e\}$, $K = \{e\}\times S_2$. Clearly $H\cap K = \{(e,e)\}$ is trivial, $G \cong H \times K$ since $S_k \cong S$, and neither $H$ nor $K$ are normal in $G$.

Comment: Umm , what are the purpose of $H$ and $K$ ?

Comment: So that we have subgroups of $G$.

Comment: And $G$ is infact isomorphic to $H \times K$ , right ?

Comment: Why should we take $H_0$ to be a subgroup of $K_0$ ? And $H_0$ is not normal where ?

Comment: Yes, clearly $H \cong H_0$ and $K \cong K_0$, so by construction $G = H_0 \times K_0 \cong H \times K$. But $H$ is not normal in $G$.

Comment: Ah ! Yes! I got everything now . Fantastic Answer !

Comment: Letting $H$ be a subgroup of $K$ is the easiest way of constructing an example where $H$ is not normal in $G$ (at least for me). Since $H_0$ is not normal in $K_0$, it follows that $H = \{e\}\times H_0$ is not normal in $K = \{e\} \times K_0$, and a fortiori it's not normal in $G$.

Comment: Can we extend this construction to say even if $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic with $H \times K$ , neither $H$ nor $K$ should be normal in $G$ ?

Comment: We can extend it so that neither $H$ nor $K$ are normal. Take a group $S$ that contains a copy of itself as a non-normal subgroup. Let $\iota\colon S \hookrightarrow S$ be an embedding with non-normal image. Then take $G = S\times S$, and $K = \{e\} \times \iota(S)$. We can then take $H = \{e\}\times \iota(\iota(S))$ in the same way as in the answer, but we could also take $H = \iota(S)\times \{e\}$ to have a situation where $H\cap K$ is trivial.

Comment: For the existence of groups like used here, let $S$ be the group of permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ that move only finitely many points, and $\iota(S)$ the subgroup of $S$ that leaves $0$ fixed (let $\iota(\pi)(0)  = 0$, and $\iota(\pi)(n) = \pi(n-1)+1$ for $n\geqslant 1$).

Comment: You mean to say $\iota (S)$ is a non-normal subgroup of $S$ but is isomorphic with $S$ ?

Comment: Yes, precisely that. To see that in the above the subgroup is not normal, conjugate it with some transposition $\tau = (0\,m)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be an element of $G$, then we have to prove that
$$g^{-1} Hg=H$$
But $G$ is isomorphic to the direct product $H\times K$, thus $g$ correspond to an element of such group that is in the form $(h, k)$. Equally, every $h \in H$ is sent by the isomorphism to an element in the form $(h, 1_K)$.

Therefore the statement we need to prove is 
$$(h^{-1} ,k^{-1} )(H, 1_K)(h,k)=(H,1_K)$$
And this is clearly true since the LHS is equal to
$$(h^{-1} Hh, k^{-1} 1_Kk)$$
And since a subgroup is closed under conjugacy
$$(h^{-1} Hh, k^{-1} 1_Kk) = (H, 1_K)$$

Comment: You are assuming a special isomorphism, under which $h\in H$ corresponds to $(h,1) \in H\times K$ and analogously for $K$. The OP explicitly stated in a comment that they don't assume _that_ isomorphism, only the existence of _some_ isomorphism between $G$ and $H\times K$.

Comment: @DanielFischer you're right, I didn't see it