# $H,K$ normal subgroups of a finite group $G$ , $G \cong H \times K$ , every element of $H$ commutes with every element of $K$ , then is $G=HK$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, direct-product

Let $H,K$ be normal subgroups of a finite group $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic with $H \times K$ and every element of $H$ commutes with every element of $K$ , then is it necessary that $G=HK$ ? ( Note that I am not assuming $H \cap K=\{e\}$ , because assuming that , since $G$ is finite , the claim would trivially be true ) .If this is not true , what if we also assume that $G$ is abelian ? Please help .  Thanks in advance

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  :No no ; that's not true ; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621124/h-k-be-subgroups-of-a-group-g-such-that-g-is-isomorphic-with-h-times-k   and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621192/h-k-be-normal-subgroups-of-g-such-that-g-is-isomorphic-with-h-times-k

Comment: I see, so you don't want the embeddings of $H$ and $K$ into $G$ to have anything to do with the isomorphism $G \cong H \times K$. That seems quite unnatural, but okay.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  : Yes , it is just an isomorphism ; not the natural embedding ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't assume anything about how $H$, $K$ lie inside $G$, then is this not trivially false. For example take $G=\{1,a,b,ab\}$ be the Klein four, and $H=K=\langle a\rangle$.

---

What is the question that you really wanted to ask?

Comment: Ah! Yes ! Thanks ( this is what I really wanted to ask :) )